# Constructors in union causing undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, unions

I get the values for `NumericType Values (10, 3.1416, 20)` to be `20, 3.1416, 20` after the object has been constructed. is the behaviour for constructors in a `union` defined?

```
union NumericType
{
    NumericType() {}

    NumericType(int i, double d, long l)
    {
        iValue = i;
        dValue = d;
        lValue = l;
    }

private:
    long        lValue; 
    int         iValue; 
    double      dValue;
};


int main()
{
     union NumericType Values ( 10, 3.1416, 20 );
}
```

Comment: I think you don't understand what a `union` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing doesn't make sense. Because it's a union, you're assigning to the same area of memory 3 times. Because you assign to `lvalue` in the constructor *last*, that's what everything remains at. All three variables are at the same location and occupy the same memory (with the exception of `dValue` which takes up 4 more bytes than the other two).

You probably want a `struct`, not a `union` (because in `struct`s, all variables are seperate and setting one to something won't affect others).

[Here's a good visualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/5dxy4b7b(v=vs.100)) (keep in mind this block is just one 8 byte chunk of memory, not 3):

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC66560.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that the elements in a union share memory, so having a constructor which initializes all of them will throw away information.

That said, this is not valid C++.

Comment: What's the correct way to initialize a union then? Does it always have to be the first element, or can it be any?

Comment: The type of initialization, if any, is compiler-dependent.